# Unable to buy item (response 7 item already owned) - UNMANAGED PRODUCT

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I'm kinda new to in-app purchases. 
I followed the sdk sample and few guides and I did succeed in working with it.
The only problem I encounter is this error
"Unable to buy item (response 7 item already owned)"

I'm handling all the purchases my self (with server handling and validations).

I've created a test package which is unmanaged, after I buy it in the first time I'm unable to rebuy this package again although its unmanaged (isn't it the whole concept of unmanaged?)

I'm using this line of code in order to open the google play inapp popup

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(BaseActivity.this,
                        Consts.PAYMENT_1_MONTH, IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_INAPP,
                        RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I have red about the version 3 managed and unmanaged are united
if this is the reason there isn't any other option (doesn't sounds very logic to me)

btw I'm using test account (maybe this is the problem?)

really hope someone can sharpen this point out for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using version 3 of in app billing (which you should be), then the product type you want is consumable. You'll need to consume your test purchase before you're able to purchase it again. See [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume) section of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, instead of lanchPurchaseFlow I needed to check if it's already own then consumeAsync